# Detect whether or not text in NSTextfield is a Dictionary word Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, key, nstextfield

Is this actually possible? If so I would like to use a simple if () statement to alert the user that he/she can not use dictionary words when entering a key for encryption.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: If you can wait for iOS 5, your patience might pay off…

Comment: @Amorya iOS has no relevance; this is a Cocoa question, not a Cocoa Touch question.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, misread the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. [Look it up in the dictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/DictionaryServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/DCSCopyTextDefinition); if it's not there, show your alert.

> … to alert the user that he/she can not use dictionary words when entering a key for encryption.

[About that.](http://xkcd.com/936/)

It's probably a good idea to show your alert if the entered key is *a single* dictionary word, but I recommend allowing multiple words.

Comment: Haha why is the link for the information about the alert (which I know how to handle) redirect to an xkcd comic hahaha.

Comment: @Bobby bob: The link is not about the alert. Read the comic; it's about the fitness of dictionary words for passwords/keys.